# OneNote Rest API and Office 365

Tags: onenote

Is there a way by which I can use OneNote Rest API to access content from Office 365 document library? My scenario is that I would like to parse my OneNote document in Office 365 document library and display it in an app. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Not as of September 2014, but we're actively investigating this support.   No plans to share yet on when we expect it, but it's a significant piece of work, so more than a couple of months I expect.